# Building product for Juno does produces Themes list empty in Preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

When building my product (using Tycho) for 4.2 'Themes' list is empty in 'Preferences' - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmTqH.png. However when I view in Eclipse 4.2 IDE list is there and all the checkboxes are present. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bundles missing which contribute the themes. Find out which ones they are and add them to your product.

Comment: Shouldn't they be there by default? Target Definitions for Indigio and Juno that I have are same except SDK feature which I think provides preferences, and in Indigo 'Appearance' page loads fine.

Comment: Things in the target platform *can* be used by the build. You still need to declare a reference from your product to have something included from the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

At least some themes are operating system specific. Therefore that might depend on the [environments](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Target_runtime_environment) specified in the Tycho build.